# jq, concatenate two values from the same sub object on different levels based on 'aws describe-instance'

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq

I know `as` statement, but can't figure out how to use it, I think I should do something like :

```
jq '
    Reservations | .[].Instances as root
    $root.Tags | .[] | select(.Key=="Name") | .Value , 
    $root.BlockDeviceMappings | $root.[].Ebs.VolumeId
' file.json
```

The goals is to iterate over each instances and map the `Tags.Value` (select on `.Key=="Name"`) and the `.Ebs.VolumeId`.

Input file  sample:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
               {
                     "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "VolumeId": "vol-fffffffffffff"
                             }
                          }
                        ],
                        "Tags": [
                            {
                                "Value": "FOO - DEV - BAR - instance-name",
                                "Key": "Name"
                            }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ReservationId": "r-xxxx"
        },
        {
              "Instances": [
                    "another same kind of sub-objects with different values like above repeated"
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The last sub object :

```
"Instances": [
     "another same kind of sub-objects with different values like above repeated"
 ]
```

is fake, it's the sub object `Instances` repeated like the fisrt one with different values for real

Expected output is :

```
FOO - DEV - BAR - instance-name:vol-fffffffffffff
```

Comment: your JSON sample is invalid.

Comment: Fixed JSON ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input, the following variation of your jq program produces the desired output:

```
(.Reservations[].Instances[]) as $root
| ($root.Tags? | .[] | select(.Key=="Name") | .Value) + ":" 
  + ($root.BlockDeviceMappings? | .[].Ebs.VolumeId)
```

There is actually no need to introduce the `$root` variable -- you could just as well write:

```
(.Reservations[].Instances[])
| (.Tags? | .[] | select(.Key=="Name").Value) + ":" 
  + (.BlockDeviceMappings? | .[].Ebs.VolumeId)
```

### Caveats

The use of "?" above is, I suspect, only required because your sample JSON is contrived.

Also, I am not really sure what the requirements are, so the above may not be what you actually want.  Once you've mastered jq's syntax, you will probably want to capture your requirements more precisely.